# TLSv1.2 compatibility in client side

Tags: tls, tls-intercept

I'm trying to connect ejb via SSL.
Server is configured for TLSv1.1.

If I set my client TLS_PROTOCOL as TLSv1.0 (on the ejb side), it throws an error.

If I set my client TLS_PROTOCOL as TLSv1.1 (on the ejb side), it connects to the server, in log like taking TLSv1.1 and gets the response successfully.

If set my client TLS_PROTOCOL as TLSv1.2 (on the ejb side) also it connects to the server, in log like taking TLSv1.1 and gets the response successfully, instead of throwing an error.

Scenario:[image]

Is this one the correct behavior?

Comment: It is unclear what your server is and what "configured as TLSv1.1" actually means in this context. Given  your description of what happens it probably means that the *minimal* (and not the *only*) TLS version is TLS 1.1 in which case this behavior is the expected one.